# Parse Swift - Subclassing PFObject - setting property causing app to hang with no error message

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, subclass

I am subclassing a Parse object called "Item". Everything that follows is based off the Parse documentation: https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-subclasses

I am trying to get the object from Parse, and simply add a local property called `thumbnailImage` which is of type `UIImage`.

```
This is my bridging header:

#ifndef My_Bridging_Header_h
#define My_Bridging_Header_h


#endif /* My_Bridging_Header_h */
#import <Parse/PFObject+Subclass.h>
```

This is my "Item.swift" file:

```
import UIKit
import Parse


class Item : PFObject, PFSubclassing {

override class func initialize() {
    struct Static {
        static var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0;
    }
    dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
        self.registerSubclass()
    }
}


@NSManaged var thumbnailImage: UIImage


static func parseClassName() -> String {
    return "Item"
}
}
```

Finally, in my viewController, the code hangs after the `"hello world"` line:

```
        let query = PFQuery(className: "Item")
        query.whereKey("expired", equalTo: false)

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (results, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                print(error)
            }

            else {

                self.itemsToDisplay.removeAll()

                print(results!.count)

                self.itemsToDisplay = results as! [Item]

                for item in self.itemsToDisplay {

                    let downloadedItemThumbnailImage = item["thumbnailImage"] as! PFFile

                    do {

                        let downloadedItemThumbnailImageData = try UIImage(data: downloadedItemThumbnailImage.getData())

                        print("hello world")
```

`//the problem line is below`

```
                        item.thumbnailImage = downloadedItemThumbnailImageData!

                        print("now I am here!")

                    }

                    catch {
                        print("error with downloaded image data")
                    }



                }
```

itemsToDisplay is an array of `[Item]`, which is my PFObject subclass.

Xcode doesn't give me any error message, though eventually I do get a memory warning and have to quit the app. Not sure what is happening.

Why doesn't this work: `item.thumbnailImage = downloadedItemThumbnailImageData!`

How do I set this local property on the subclassed PFObject?

Lastly, I have registered my subclass at the top of my AppDelegate.swift file:

`// Parse Register Subclasses
        Item.registerSubclass()`

Comment: Are you use Xcode does not give you any error messages? That doesn't sound right. How do you know it's that line if there's no error message then?

Comment: I know because I have `print` statements before and after that line, and the `print` statement before prints out, while the `print` statement after does not print. Help!

Comment: My best guess is that you are explicitly unwrapping optionals and it's nil while you unwrap it. You should use the `if let` pattern.

Comment: Thanks Enrico. I added the `if let` stuff but it didn't make a difference. I can't figure out what's going on. There is some more information below in my other comments. Maybe this will give you an idea?

Answer (score 1):

When subclassing PFObject, you do not want to have a UIImage directly as a property. Instead, make it a PFFile. This allows you to download the file, and then get the image data.

If you want to do this all in the same class, you could download the file and then set the property without using @NSManaged, however, this probably wouldn't offer any benefit, and keeps the image in memory as long as the object is.

Comment: I've tried a similar approach already and it wasn't working. For example, in my Parse object I already have a `thumbnailImage` PFFile property. When I'm building my table from these objects, the below code works, but it is really slow to retrieve/download the thumbnails. I can't seem to paste the code in, but basically I'm running a `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock` and downloading the PFFile in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function, as they cells are built. Again, this works but is really slow.

Comment: So then, based on your suggestion, I tried something else. I added a `PFFile` property to my local `Item` subclass. After running a query to get all of my Parse objects, I set the returned array to an array of `[Item]`, just like before. Then I set `item.thumbnailImagePFFile = item["thumbnailImage"] as! PFFile`. However, when I try to actually download the `thumbnailImage`, it doesn't get past my `print` statement, just like in my original question, it hangs here: `item.thumbnailImage = try! UIImage(data: item.thumbnailImagePFFile.getData())!`

Comment: So, basically, I'm trying to figure out how to download all of the thumbnail image to my `PFObject` subclass, so that when I actually build my cells using `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, it is fast. Because the way I currently have it working, it is really slow (like 10 seconds for 7 thumbnails to appear), which is obviously really slow! Help!

Comment: You want to grab the data in the background, not on the main thread. I do something like this. The reuse count is helpful if you will be scrolling. It's purpose is that once you get it back from the background, it's still the same image in that cell:

        self.thumbnail.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil && cell.reuseCount == reuseCount {
                cell.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use image into the subclass in swift using Parse SDK then you can use this solution.

```
import Parse

class Person: PFObject, PFSubclassing{
    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var age: Int
    @NSManaged var imageFile: PFFileObject!
    class func parseClassName() -> String {
        return "Person"
    }   
}

//By writing this function you can add your data to the server with image data
func addData(){
    let person = Person()
    person.name = "Muhammad ABBAS"
    person.age = 21
    let image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "IMAGENAME") // Image litral
    // if your image is .jpeg or .jpg then write this 
    person.imageFile = PFFileObject(data: image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 100)!)
    person.saveInBackground { success, error in
        if success{
            print("Successfully Data Upload")
        }else{
            print("Not uploaded the data")
        }
    }
}
```

if your image is .png then write this
`person.imageFile = PFFileObject(data: image.pngData()!)` 
instead of
`person.imageFile = PFFileObject(data: image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 100)!)`